# After crash and reload DB connection to this DB not recreatew

Tags: spring, connection, datasource

I have spring boot server with connection to Oracle. Server worck on tomcat server.

Some time DB admin kill my session or DB crash. And After that serve can not recreate DataSorce. I get

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
```

I have this configs:

```
spring.datasource.dbcp.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.dbcp.validation-query=validationQuery=select 1 from dual
```

But when DB recovering - conection not recreate. But after reload server all work fine.

I 2 data sorce and second config has:

```
spring.secondary.dbcp.test-on-borrow=true
spring.secondary.dbcp.validation-query=validationQuery=select 1 from dual
```

Comment: Are you sure that your validation query is right? Try with spring.dbcp.validation-query= SELECT 1

Comment: Yes I sure that my validation query is right

Comment: Oh, you are right. This should work: spring.datasource.dbcp.validation-query=select 1 from dual